# War overlay conflict

Tags: maven, war

I have a maven dependency that looks like this:

`<dependency>
  <type>war</type>
  <scope>runtime</scope>...
</dependency>`

and it has conflicts with my own web files (it provides index.jsp) for example. What is the correct
way to move all of the resources it provides under some sub path? Possibly `/depname/index.jsp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use the [targetPath attribute](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) of the overlay plugin.

> **targetPath** - the target relative path in the webapp structure, which is only available for overlays of type war. By default, the content of the overlay is added in the root structure of the webapp.